# MP3 Audio Python

Tags: python, audio, mp3

I am trying to play a file, but I do not know the command. Here is the image as to what my project looks like, and I am wondering if there is a way I can play the audio.

[image: Here is a screenshot of my project structure.]

Comment: Welcome to So.  Before you post another question, please take the [tour], read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is pygame. Install via:

```
    pip3 install pygame
```

Download a .wav file to your .py file direction. Define a push button and connect to this function:

```
    def somesound(self):
        pygame.mixer.init()
        pygame.mixer.music.load('somesound.wav') # Pygame allows *.wav                       
        pygame.mixer.music.play(1) # For 1 second
```

Comment: How does it know which file to play?

Comment: For example you .wav file in your Downloads file. You can write:  /home/xxx/Downloads/sound.wav in the load line. Pygame is gonna find the file in order to play.

Comment: Okay! Which line do I replace with the location of the file?